# Run-time error '3071' when execute the query in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to run a query in Access to create a report with an added formula. Running the query with 40 connections/IDs has no issues, however, when I increase the number of connections/IDs, I receive the following errors when the data query includes more than 50 connections/IDs.

> Run-time error '3017': This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is
> too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may
> contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression
> by assigning parts of the expression to variables.

Here's the query I've been using. Any assistance from those experienced in this area would be greatly appreciated.

```
ccTable ("Table_Transmission")
strsqle6 = "SELECT CmpT3.MSSLID, CmpT3.CONNECTIONMEMBERNAME, CmpT3.[Peak Input_Consumption], CmpT3.[Offpeak Input_Consumption], CmpT3.[Peak Energy Charge], CmpT3.[Offpeak Energy Charge], [Input_Contract]![Tension Type] AS [Tension Type],[Input_Contract].[Contracted Capacity],Max([Input_Consumption]![VALUE]*2) AS [Max Demand],Max(Round(IIf(([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]+[CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption])*0.62<[CmpT4]![ReactiveQty],[CmpT4]![ReactiveQty]-([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]+[CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption])*0.62,0),3)) AS [Reactive Energy Qty],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]*[Input_Transmission]![Peak UOS],2)) AS [Peak UOS Amt],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]*0.0081,2)) AS [Peak UOS Amt1],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]*0.0048,2)) AS [Peak UOS Amt2],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]*0.0031,2)) AS [Peak UOS Amt3],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption]*[Input_Transmission]![Offpeak UOS],2)) AS [Offpeak UOS Amt]," _
& "Max(Round([CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption]*0.0081,2)) AS [Offpeak UOS Amt1],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption]*0.0048,2)) AS [Offpeak UOS Amt2],Max(Round([CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption]*0.0031,2)) AS [Offpeak UOS Amt3]," _
& "Max(IIf([Input_Contract]![Contracted Capacity]='NA',0,Round([Input_Contract]![Contracted Capacity]*[Input_Transmission]![CC],2))) AS [CC Amt], Max(IIf([Input_Contract]![Contracted Capacity]='NA',0,IIf(([Input_Consumption]![VALUE]*2-[Input_Contract]![Contracted Capacity])>0,Round(([Input_Consumption]![VALUE]*2-[Input_Contract]![Contracted Capacity])*[Input_Transmission]![UCC],2),0))) AS [UCC Amt]," _
& "Max(Round(IIf(([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]+[CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption])*0.62<[CmpT4]![ReactiveQty],[CmpT4]![ReactiveQty]-([CmpT3]![Peak Input_Consumption]+[CmpT3]![Offpeak Input_Consumption])*0.62,0)*[Input_Transmission]![Reactive],2)) AS [Reactive Amt]" _
& "INTO Table_Transmission FROM (([Input_Transmission] INNER JOIN (CmpT3 INNER JOIN [Input_Contract] ON CmpT3.MSSLID = [Input_Contract].[MSSL ID]) ON [Input_Transmission].[Tension Type] = [Input_Contract].[Tension Type]) INNER JOIN Input_Consumption ON (CmpT3.CONNECTIONMEMBERNAME = Input_Consumption.CONNECTIONMEMBERNAME) AND ([Input_Contract].[MSSL ID] = Input_Consumption.MSSLID)) INNER JOIN CmpT4 ON [Input_Contract].[MSSL ID] = CmpT4.MSSLID " _
& "GROUP BY CmpT3.MSSLID, CmpT3.CONNECTIONMEMBERNAME, CmpT3.[Peak Input_Consumption], CmpT3.[Offpeak Input_Consumption], CmpT3.[Peak Energy Charge], CmpT3.[Offpeak Energy Charge], [Input_Contract]![Tension Type], [Input_Contract].[Contracted Capacity]" _
& "HAVING (((CmpT3.CONNECTIONMEMBERNAME)='PLE_CM_EnergywithoutTLF'));"
DoCmd.RunSQL strsqle6
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean by "40 connections/IDs".

Comment: Missing a space at the end of `"AS [Reactive Amt]"` which causes string to run together when concatenating next line `& "INTO`, however, probably not an issue because of bracketing of field name.

Comment: The error message is clear. It is all the `Max(Round(IIf( ...)))` it can't figure out. So, split the query in two or more queries. Also, you can't reliably compare values from `Round` because of floating point errors. If these values are critical, see my repository at **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: Hi, may i know how can i split the query into 2 or more queries?